# How to make hover dynamic in CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm using Angular v1.5.4. 
The project is a personal blog. 
Currently in the early prototyping stage.

Here is my use case: User hovers over button. If that button has the class 'active' applied to it (ng-class sets that button to active, or if the property 'clicked' is true in the JSON in the controller), make the hover color a nice blue. If that button is not currently active, make the button black (the color it is now).

The code I have now:

HTML:

```
 <div class="buttons" ng-controller="ButtonController as buttons">
    <ul>

       <li ng-repeat = "button in buttons.buttonsList"
           ng-class="{active: button.isClicked == true}"
           ng-click="button.isClicked = !button.isClicked">

         <p>{{button.name}}</p>

       </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  float: left;
}

li p {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover{
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

ButtonController.js:

```
function ButtonController() {
  this.buttonsList = [{
    name: 'Home',
    description: 'This button returns the user to the home page.',
    clicked: false
  },{
    name: 'Music',
    description: 'This button takes the user to a page where I write about music I like.',
    clicked: false
  }];
}

angular
  .module('app')
  .controller('ButtonController', ButtonController);
```

How do I make the li:hover CSS code dynamic based on the state of the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your CSS to care about what the class is...

Change

```
li:hover{
  background-color: #111;
}
```

to

```
.active:hover{
  background-color: #111;
}
```